# Default URL for XMLHttpRequest

Tags: xmlhttprequest

Similarly to how a `<form>` with either no `action` attribute or an empty one, is it consistent and reliable behaviour that an XMLHttpRequest with en empty string given to the URL parameter will request the current URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimentation, it appears the answer is "No". In fact, the URL argument is required and will cause an error.