# Valid URL strings for XMLHttpRequest POST request to the current URL

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

In the `open()` method of `XMLHttpRequest`, is an empty string for the `url` parameter valid? Assuming I want to POST a form on the current page to the same page, is:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', '');
```

...effectively equivalent to:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', window.location.href);
```

...? Is there any difference between using `''` and `window.location.href` for the `url` parameter, in this case?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12955019/default-url-for-xmlhttprequest) says an empty string doesn't work, but doesn't explain why (and it *does* work through my own experimentation). I can't find a definitive answer in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my understanding is that the `url`, if relative, is joined with the current base URL by the browser. therefore `''` the empty string should work just as well as window.location.href. see https://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-open()-method

Comment: That appears to be correct. Especially when reading this point: `Let parsed URL be the result of parsing url with base.`. Thanks!